# Symfony project doesn't work while moving it from local to shared network

Tags: symfony

I'm trying to move my project that works fine in my local environment to a shared one. But all i get is a blank page.

After some researches i found out that my session isn't created and all the components that doesn't need a session works fine.

I really don't understand why it's not working have anyone faced the same issue with symfony ?

Comment: Check logs for errors. If you have some, paste their messages here. How did you found out that it's about session? We need more info to help you. Anyway, I would guess that `var/sessions` directory is not writable for web server's user. That's the most common issue.

Comment: It could be a permission problem. Does the user the webserver process runs under has permissions to write to the log and cache folders?

Comment: I think that is a permissions issue on directory `var\sessions`.

Comment: i have all the permissions to the var\sessions directory and I get nothing on the logs :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you have problems with your php sessions not being created try to change the configuration to use a folder you have access to and can set the permissions (e.g. `var/sessions`). Please check out [the official documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/session/sessions_directory.html) about session config. By default symfony uses the settings of the php.ini, but you can change the location of the session like this:

```
# app/config/config.yml
framework:
    session:
        handler_id: session.handler.native_file
        save_path: "%kernel.root_dir%/../var/sessions/%kernel.environment%"
```